# Mock set return type based on object's properties and not its reference

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm facing an issue on my unit tests because of the way the mock framework (`NSubstitute`) works.

I want to test a method that receives a parameter and inside of that method I am creating a new object using the new operator and I'm passing this new object to a builder that will build another object. My problem is that I cannot mock the builder to return what I want because when I will configure the return object, it will do it based on the reference.

So if my new created object looks like this:

```
class MyReferenceType
{
    public String Property1 { get; set; }

    public String Property2 { get; set; }

    public String Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

And if my mock if I will create a new object of type `MyReferenceType` and I will say that

```
myBuilder.Build(myReferenceTypeObject).Returns(anotherObject);
```

In my method the object `myReferenceTypeObject` will have another reference and it will not return my desired object.

So is there a way to configure the return object of a mock based on the object's property content and not on it's reference?

Here is some code:

```
class Mapper
{
    private Builder builder;
    public Mapper(Builder builder)
    {
        this.builder = builder;
    }

    public string Map(string data)
    {
        //process the string 

        MyReferenceType obj = new MyReferenceType();

        return this.builder.Build(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete example we can test? That will make it a lot easier to verify a solution.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Here you have it

Comment: What is `Builder`? Where is the test that's trying to use it? Ideally, we should be able to copy, paste, compile and run the example without having to guess at anything else.

Comment: The code is huge... but this is a simple version of it... I think nobody puts all the production code here... and you can see that builder.Build() will return a string from the type MyReferenceType

Comment: I wasn't asking you to post the whole of your production code. I was asking you to post a complete example. Yes, I could probably spend more time guessing at what the rest of the code looks like, but a) I might guess incorrectly, wasting everyone's time; b) it's much more appropriate for *one* person (the person asking for help) to spend a little time putting a complete example together in the question than *everyone* who tries to help you having to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get the references to match. You have no control of that object outside of the method under test because it is being initialized within the method.

Use `Arg.Any<T>()` for the argument to make the mock expectation more flexible when being exercised as it will ignore the specific argument passed.

Based on the code example provided, a simple test can look like

```
//Arrange
var data = "some data";
var myBuilder = Substitute.For<Builder>();
var expected = "some value";
myBuilder.Build(Arg.Any<MyReferenceType>()).Returns(expected);

var subject = new Mapper(myBuilder);

//Act
var actual = subject.Map(data);

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

This will allow the mock to behave as expected when invoked.

If you want to conditionally match the argument use `Arg.Is<T>(Predicate<T> condition)`

```
myBuilder
  .Build(Arg.Is<MyReferenceType>(_ => _.Property1 == "value1" && _.Property2 == "value2"))
  .Returns(expected);
```

the behavior should be the same as expected above provided that the passed argument satisfies the expected condition.

Reference [NSubstitute: Argument matchers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer on the question, but another approach in testing, which eliminate problems you are facing.

Instead of creating a mock use actual implementation of `Builder` - then you test will be straightforward

```
// Arrange
var givenData = "some data";
var expected = "transformed data";

var builder = new Builder();
var mapper = new Mapper(builder);

// Act
var actual = mapper.Map(data);

// Assert
actual.Should().Be(expected);
```

Using actual implementation of `Builder` will give you possibility to make changes inside `Map` method and changes to `Builder` without changing tests.

Mock only classes/methods which makes your tests slow.